Plugins dependencies without version (Migration version catalogs)
I started migrating my project to use the new version catalogs, and plugins without version give an error saying that version is needed.
How do I add the plugin below to the toml file since there is no version?
Documentation kotlin parcelize
id("kotlin-parcelize")


Found the answer after reading the documentation for the second time.
Documentation new version catalogs

The following code shows how to define the com.android.application
plugin in the top and module level build.gradle.kts files. Use alias
for plugins that come from the version catalog file and id for plugins
that don't come from the version catalog file, such as convention
plugins.

Conclusion
If there is no version, use id.
id("kotlin-parcelize")


Since my question related to what to do with plugins without versions, I accepted this answer. Leviathan's answer is also valid since you can use it.

Use the Kotlin version:
[versions]
kotlin = "2.0.0" # or whatever kotlin version you use for your app

[plugins]
kotlin-parcelize = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize", version.ref = "kotlin" }

Then use it in your build.gradle the same as the other plugins:
alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.parcelize)

